# Copy/Move Entire Line To End Of The Line Above

Tags: bash, shell-scripting, grep, sed, awk

I have a file that looks like the following:

```
/path/to/a/very/long/path
       0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I need to move the line starting with a number (this can be any value not necessarily 0) to the end of the preceding line so that it looks like the following:

```
/path/to/a/very/long/path 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Do you have more than one pair of such lines in the file?

Comment: Yes, multiple lines that all read and start with the long path followed by the next line with the numeric values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some `awk` program can do the work line this:

```
awk '{if(NR%2==0) {print var,$0} else {var=$0}}' input_file >output_file
```

It use `awk` internal variable `NR` which is the number of current line.

Here is example:

```
# cat qs
/path/to/a/very/long/path
       0 0 0 0 0 0
/path/to/a/very/long/path
       1 2 0 0 0 0


# awk '{if(NR%2==0) {print var,$0} else {var=$0}}' qs
/path/to/a/very/long/path        0 0 0 0 0 0
/path/to/a/very/long/path        1 2 0 0 0 0
```